# How I can merge different objects of a theme by equal meaning of one attribute of a field (ArcMap)?

Tags: arcmap, merge

Could somebody advise, how I can combine (merge)  different objects of a shp theme with equal meaning of one attribute of a field (in ArcMap)?
I have shp theme with many objects, in the field "A" some of them have value “1”, some others “2”, others – “3”, etc
I need to combine all object with A=1 in a single object, all objects with A=2 – in a single as well, etc for all objects of the shp theme.

It seems very simple operation, but I can’t find this possibility in ArcMap. ((

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is "dissolve":

Dissolve (Data Management)

Summary

Aggregates features based on specified attributes.
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000005n000000